# oracle: primary key column in a materialized view

Tags: oracle

The task is to create a materialized view with the primary key on some unique column, so the materialized view could be replicated to another DB. The problem is that there are no unique columns because I had to join a very large number of tables, so I can not use the IDs from the joined tables, as they are not unique anymore in my materialized view.

First of all I have to create a view, because there are subqueries in the select:

```
CREATE VIEW V_CONTRACTS
AS

SELECT 
     ID.NEXTVAL,
     C.*
FROM (SELECT <lots of columns>
      FROM CONTRACT
      <lots of joins>
      WHERE <some filters>) C
;
```

But the error is thrown:

```
ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
```

Then I will create the materialized view as:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW CONTRACTS
AS
SELECT * FROM V_CONTRACTS;
```

Comment: Why not have a combination of unique columns to create a composite primary key?

Comment: why do you need the view?  A mat view can have subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ROW_NUMBER analytic function to give you a number column.

```
CREATE VIEW V_TEST
AS

SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY col1 , col2 ) as idx,
     C.*
FROM ( SELECT 'A' as col1, 'B' as col2 FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 'C' as col1, 'D' as col2 FROM DUAL
       UNION
       SELECT 'E' as col1, 'F' as col2 FROM DUAL
     ) C ;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_test
AS     
SELECT * FROM V_TEST ;   

SELECT * FROM mv_test ;
```